# How I am able to do following in Php, it is not throwing any error, please explain

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php

 class test
 {

   function test_print($myvar)
   {
      echo $myvar;
   }
 }

  $my_test = new test();
  $my_test->a = 3;
  $my_test->test_print($my_test->a);

?>
```

How I am able to create a new variable dynamically outside class, this is not Oops.. please correct if I am missing something.

Comment: Is your question, why is this allowed?

Comment: @Orbling Yes, and if you can refer some docs also

Answer (score 3):

PHP allows dynamic properties, like other dynamic languages, such as JavaScript.

It can be useful, but generally is not used an awful lot in PHP.

There was a blog article I found, that shows how you can [prevent dynamic properties](http://www.mattvsworld.com/blog/2010/02/constraining-php-dynamic-properties/) if you really desire it gone.

Though [it is faster](http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass) to use dynamic properties directly than using the [`__get()` and `__set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)  magic methods.

Comment: Good links; I found those also. However, I haven't found in the PHP docs where it explicitly allows/describes dynamic properties. Oh well.

Comment: @Wiseguy: PHP design is not always overly well committed to documentation.  A lot of the ideas tend to occur in chat channels. ;-)

Comment: True enough, though PHP documentation is generally very good compared to some other languages, at least in regard to functions/libraries if not concepts/behaviors.

Comment: @Wiseguy: True, I often despair at the poverty of documentation of some languages.  Flash AS2/3 normally causes great grief in that regard.